# ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::Error: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I migrated my db from Sqlite to Postgres. Now when I try to create a new record

`Account.create! code:"0001", name:"foo"`

I got this error

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) already exists.`

It seems like the autoincrement is not working. Do I need some extra configuration???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `sequence value` of your PG table manually using pgAdminIII.
Go to your Database -> Sequences, click on your table correspondent to your model and change it's `Current value`.